# Using Junit 4's Timeout @Rule with Spring's AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

Tags: spring, junit, junit4

When i use Junit's org.junit.rules.Timeout with spring's base class AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests, i get this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

The log output shows:

```
2010-07-20 09:20:16 INFO  [TransactionalTestExecutionListener.startNewTransaction] Began transaction (1): transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@6a1fbe]; rollback [true]
2010-07-20 09:20:16 INFO  [TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction] Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [[TestContext@17b60b6 testClass = MyIntegrationTest, locations = array<String>['classpath:/context.xml', 'classpath:/junit-context.xml'], testInstance = MyIntegrationTest@10a4d7c, testMethod = myTest@MyIntegrationTest, testException = org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress]]
```

Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/context.xml", "classpath:/junit-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class MyIntegrationTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Rule public Timeout globalTimeout = new Timeout(30000);

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // transactional code here saving to the database...
    }
}
```

However whenever i comment out the rule, it all works fine.

How can i marry these two together to work correctly?

Comment: I've figured out that the Timeout class starts a new thread and runs my test in it. That's why my transaction gets created but my code is not wrapped in it. Now to figure out how to get it to work how i want...

Comment: The reason why the log shows a transaction being setup and shutdown is that it is living on the original thread which actually the timer is living on. And probably because the transaction uses some sort of ThreadLocal instance, my code does not get wrapped in a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL.

You can simply also annotate your test method with @Transactional(timeout = 30) for a 30 second timeout. Which is a lot simpler.

Comment: Minor note that timeout is in milliseconds, not seconds

Comment: To annotate a single test might not be really helpful if the timeout shall be applied to a lot of tests. Think of more tests in subclasses of MyIntegrationTest. The variable name globalTimeout suggest that the timeout shall be applied to more than one test.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, i worked it out. The way i solved it was to setup the transaction programatically.

```
@Autowired TransactionManager transactionManager;

@Test
public void test() {     
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            status.setRollbackOnly();

            // DO YOUR TEST LOGIC HERE
        }
     });
}
```

Hope it helps.